# MongoDB - How to combine two Sorts

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to stipulate the sort into a critical point of time: $currentDate.
That means, to sort the old dates in descending order, but the future dates in ascending order.

```
---future---
18.5
17.5
16.5
---today---
14.5
13.5
12.5
---past---
```

to become:

```
---future---
16.5
17.5
18.5
---today--
14.5
13.5
12.5
---past---
```

It's gonna be done with aggregation framework, might be consist of $cond, and I would prefer it to begin with a descending sort to take advantage of the index. I will appreciate any piece of advice!

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd say this is impossible, since `$sort` is always going to be applied to *all* documents. You might be better off doing two queries and merge the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot Markus, I will do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting my own question in 3 years, and I've come to a neat solution by myself, making this with only one query.

Given the special date field is *"stipulatedDate"*, we'll create another date field for the special sort purpose, called *"stipulatedDateSort"*. This one is based on our first requirement, but is *null* for the second. This will give us a chance to have another sort-by field inside *$sort* to meet our second requirement, and thus making everything in only one query.

```
db.brands.aggregate([
{
    $addFields: {
        'activities.stipulatedDateSort': {
            $cond: {
                if: { $gt: [ '$activities.stipulatedDate', new Date() ] },
                then: "$activities.stipulatedDate",
                else: null
            }
        },
    }
},
{
    $sort: {
        'activities.stipulatedDateSort': 1,
        'activities.stipulatedDate': -1
    }
}
])
```

That's a knockout.